# How to fix "TypeError: unbound method " while working with Kivy and python

Tags: python, kivy

I was working with **python 2.7 and kivy v1.9.0** running a sample code ends with an error

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

Error: 
 TypeError: unbound method run() must be called with MyApp instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Could any body explain the error with proper solution.

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code you run ? This error usually arises with `MyApp.run()` instead of `MyApp().run()`.

Comment: Yes I have just copy pasted the same code here which i have used.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/dDgSRIW0MEM see this it will helps to u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of your app if you want to `run()` it so
I'm pretty sure the code that raised such error must have treated `run()` as a class method (`MyApp.run()`) which is not the proper way of running a kivy app. The snippet you provided runs without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with instance creation and returning?

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l =Label(text='Hello world')
        return l
```